# when the string is returned from a function, it prints outs incorrectly if there is and end line before it

Tags: c++, arrays, char

```
char *fractToBin(unsigned long long num)
{
  char bin[100];
  for(int i=0; i<23; i++)
      bin[i] = '0';
  bin[23] = '\0';

  char *temp = new char[100];
  int count = 0;
  int i;
  int it = num;

  while(num != 0)
  {
      count++;
      num /= 10;
  }

  int base = pow(10, count);

  for(i = 0; i<23; i++)
  {
      it = it * 2;
      if(it > base)
      {
        it = it - base;
        bin[i] = '1';
      }
      else if(it < base) 
        bin[i] = '0';
      else if (it == base)
      {
        bin[i] = '1';
        break;
      }
  }
  temp = bin;

  return temp;
}

int main()
{
  char *s;
  s = fractToBin(625);
  cout << endl; //if this is here then it prints out wrong value
  cout << s << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The fracToBin function converts the fractional part of a float to binary. 0.625 is changed to its whole number to do the converting. The binary is outputted correctly if there is no endl printed before it.

I been trying to figure out whats wrong but couldn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This would be you assigning `temp` the address of a local array in your function  : `temp = bin;`, and this would be you returning that address as your function result: `return temp;` and invoking *undefined behavior* the moment you evaluate said-address on the caller side. The memory leak is the final insult to injury.

Comment: Consider using `std::string` instead of char arrays; no need to complicate your code with memory allocation issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to a local variable.  The fact that it works sometimes is part of the undefined behavior.

`temp = bin;` just assigns the pointer to the address of `bin` and leaks the memory you allocated since you don't have a pointer to it to delete it anymore.

Either use `strcpy` to copy the data from `bin` to `temp` or just use `temp` directly instead of `bin`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem come from the following parts of the code :

```
char bin[100];
```

You declare a static tab here, this pointer will be valid only during the existence of the scope.

```
char *temp = new char[100];
```

Here you allocate a new pointer, with the new keyword, you will have to delete this pointer after finish using it.

```
temp = bin;
return temp;
```

Here you copy the address of your local pointer (bin) in temp. This copy the address of the pointer not the content. You have to copy the content in the new pointer to do it correctly.
By returning the address of bin, you return a pointer pointer on "free" memory. This mean it can be reused by any other program. By printing an std::enld; the program may be reussing the part of the memory released and messing with the data.